# How to generate signed app bundle using jenkins?

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, google-play-services, jenkins-plugins

Using jenkins i am able to generate a release app bundle for my app but, I am stuck in the next step which involves generating a signed app bundle for my app so that i can update my build on playstore. So is there a plugin or any other way by which i can generate signed app bundle for my app on jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

This could be done by:

1. Configuring the Android app's build.gradle file to pick up the signing info from environment variables if they are available.
2. Configuring the signing key, alias and password(s) as Credentials in the Jenkins job (secret file, secret text...) via the Jenkins UI.
3. Using the Credentials Binding plugin to set the environment variables from the credentials in the Jenkinsfile, and thus pass them to build.gradle.

Extract from `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def myStoreFile = System.getenv('MY_STORE_FILE')
def myStorePassword = System.getenv('MY_STORE_PASSWORD')
def myKeyAlias = System.getenv('MY_KEY_ALIAS')
def myKeyPassword = System.getenv('MY_KEY_PASSWORD')

android {
     ...
     
     signingConfigs {
         release {
            if (myStoreFile) {
                storeFile rootProject.file(myStoreFile)
                storePassword myStorePassword
                keyAlias myKeyAlias
                keyPassword myKeyPassword
            }
         }
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
            ...
     
            if (myStoreFile && myStorePassword && myKeyAlias && myKeyPassword) {
                 signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
         }
     
     }
     ...
}
```

Extract from Jenkinsfile:

```
stage ('Build and Sign Android Bundle') {
  ...
 
  steps {
    // Signing parameters are configured in Jenkins (here we use secret file, secret text and username with password respectively)
    // and are passed to the build.gradle file using the environment variables (MY_STORE_FILE, MY_KEY_ALIAS etc)
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'android-store-file', variable: 'MY_STORE_FILE'),
                     string(credentialsId: 'android-store-password', variable: 'MY_STORE_PASSWORD'),
                     usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'android-key', usernameVariable: 'MY_KEY_ALIAS', passwordVariable: 'MY_KEY_PASSWORD')]) {
    
      dir ('android-app-root-directory') {        
        sh 'gradle clean bundleRelease'
      }
    }
  }
}
```